# discord embed not wanting to send

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My embed for a command won't send. Im pretty sure there is a typo somewhere but i can't seem to find it. Is there a problem with my embed? Thx

```
@bot.command(aliases=['bal'])
async def balance(ctx, member : discord.Member = None):
  if not member:
    member = ctx.author
  await open_account(member)

  users = await get_bank_data()
  user = member

  wallet_amount = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
  bank_amount = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

  embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{member.name}'s Balance", color=0x00FFFF)
  embed.add_field(name="Wallet", value=f"{wallet_amount} Ulti Coins!", incline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Bank", value=f"{bank_amount} Ulti Coins!", incline=False)
  embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
  embed.set_footer(text="Your total amount is saved across all servers that I'm in!")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, it is `inline` not `incline`